# NuGet ANGLE eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT NoContextError

Tags: c++, opengl-es, nuget

My goal is to run OpenGL ES in a platform-indepedent way.  Every platform except for Windows has it natively.  I'm attempting to use the ANGLE project that's now a NuGet package inside Visual Studio 2015.

In attempting to get something simple going:

```
    EGLint attribs[] = {
        EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_TYPE_ANGLE,
        EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_TYPE_DEFAULT_ANGLE,
        EGL_NONE
    };
    auto display = eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT(EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_ANGLE, GetDC(NULL), attribs);
```

Something this simple causes Microsoft C++ exception: NoContextError at memory location 0x001CDFB4.

Oddly enough, if I download ANGLE and run the samples, they work fine.  Even if I dumb down the code to the above snippet.

I've made sure libEGL.dll and libGLESv2.dll are the only Modules loaded - that is, opengl32.dll is not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only solution was to simply not use NuGet.  Clearly the source code is different.  And it isn't too useful without the source code as they don't provide any PDBs to figure anything out.